# How to refer to previous cell in a data-frame column (lagged cell), in R

Tags: r

I’m working in R and am trying to find a way to refer to the previous cell within a vector when that vector belongs to a data frame. By previous cell, I’m essentially hoping for a “lag” command of some sort so that I can compare one cell to the cell previous. As an example, I have these data:

```
A <- c(1,0,0,0,1,0,0)
B <- c(1,1,1,1,1,0,0)
AB_df <- cbind (A,B)
```

What I want is for a given cell in a given row, if that cell’s value is less than the previous cell’s value for the same column vector, to return a value of 1 and if not to return a value of 0. For this example, the new columns would be called “A-flag” and “B-flag” below.

```
A   B   A-flag  B-flag
1   1   0       0
0   1   1       0
0   1   0       0
0   1   0       0
1   1   0       0
0   0   1       1
0   0   0       0
```

Any suggestions for syntax that can do this? Ideally, to just create a new column variable into an existing data-frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution using `dplyr` package and it's `lag` method:

```
library(dplyr)
AB_df <- data.frame(A = A, B = B)
AB_df %>% mutate(A.flag = ifelse(A < lag(A, default = 0), 1, 0),
                 B.flag = ifelse(B < lag(B, default = 0), 1, 0))
  A B A.flag B.flag
1 1 1      0      0
2 0 1      1      0
3 0 1      0      0
4 0 1      0      0
5 1 1      0      0
6 0 0      1      1
7 0 0      0      0
```